# preventing socket server/ client performance issues

Tags: java, php, sockets, client, server

I am tailoring my php website to connect to my java server by creating a socket connection every single web request. Within each request, I am sending about six to ten total Strings back and forth. Say a user logs in, clicks around ten times, it is not uncommon for that user to have created ten socket connections causing the transaction of ~80 Strings between server and client. I notice absolutely zero performance issues with my one connection as I test.

Before I advance any further, I want to make sure this isn't a terrible design. Imagine I had 500 users, all click ten times in ten seconds total... that's (500 * 10 * ~8) 40,000 Strings being sent or received in 10 seconds.

If I proceed with this method, is it possible to run into issues down the road? I am not factoring in hardware, strictly numbers here.

A possible solution, if this is a problem, is to take those 3-5 Strings, and send them as one. Then the server will separate them, and respond accordingly. This is my first stab at a server/ client concept, so I am really unsure on how to move forward. Perhaps there are standards that are known to preform the best.

Thank you for your input.

Brent

Comment: You should keep persistent connection and don't open new socket for every request.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj you cannot (or it is not best practice) to pass a socket obj from page to page in php. correct me if I'm wrong.